# word that means "assign/unassign"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for one word that would mean "assign" and "unassign" something to a user.

I have a software which has a page full of usernames. Next to each username we have a button which will take me to another page where I can "assign" an application to that particular user or "unassign" if it is already assigned.

So I want to know if there is a common word for "assign/unassign" which I can use for that button.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the naming of things in computer programs is explicitly off-topic according to our Help Center.

Comment: I am asking for an English word for Assign/Unassign. Whether i use the word in computer program or anywhere in the world - how is it off-topic?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that such a word exists? Remember, you said common word, too. We’re trying to provide answers here to real problems. We cannot name everyone’s program thingies for them. Can you think of real-world scenarios where such a word would naturally find a home that has nothing to do with computer programming? Please explain some of those. Also, please show us how you would use this word in actual sentences involving these real-world situations.

Comment: I dont know if such a word exists. And that is exactly what i asked in my post. "i want to know if there is a common word for Assign/Unassign".

Comment: I have been referring this website for English words and tried to post my very first question to use some help. Thanks! Please close it (because i am not sure if i can do that myself)

Comment: As you want a generic term for assign/unassign, and the button isn't an action but takes you to another page, consider *assignments* as a label.

Comment: The "correct" solution is to have the button's label change from "Assign" to "Unassign" once the item has been assigned, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think changing the label from Assign to Unassign should work. Thanks again :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the naming of things in computer programs is explicitly off-topic according to our Help Center.

Comment: The word "toggle" is very handy for software developers. Just say "toggle assignment."

Comment: The single word request tag explains that you should "INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used". If you updated your question to include a sentence instead of just asking for us to label your button for you, I think it would make your question more clearly on topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the **enrolled** and **Disenroll/withdraw**. But then again it's very contextual as to what your software meant by that.